# Exclamation mark in Rails model method not found when object is passed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 3.2. I have the following for mailer action:

```
# shop.rb
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base 
  def deliver_update_notification!(user)
    version = self.versions(user).last
    EditorMailer.updated_spot(self, version).deliver
  end
end

# shops_controller.rb
class ShopsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
    if @shop.update_attributes(params[:shop])
      @shop.deliver_update_notification!(current_user)
      redirect_to shop_path(@shop)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
end
```

Somehow when I pass in the `current_user` object to the method `deliver_update_notification!`, it throws an error saying the method cannot be found. If changed the method to not accept any object, the method works. Why is this behaving this way?

Also, I don't remember why I have the exclamation mark in the method. Saw it from somewhere. What's the purpose of the exclamation mark?

Thanks.

Comment: The purpose of the exclamation mark is to designate that you're making a destructive action (either you're modifying the object or otherwise doing some action that cannot be undone). As for your other question... I dunno, did you not save the Shop file or something? Seems like it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclamation marks are supposed to indicate that the method is "dangerous" and edits the value of the object which calls it. Not sure how to define bang methods but you can always just not use the '!' and make it a dangerous method on its own.